# unable to start hive on master node :SafeMode Exception

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive

when i run this command on master note in

```
hadoop
hdumer@HadoopMaster:~$ hive
```

However Hadoop multinode is working fine

it shows following errors:

> Logging initialized using configuration in
>   jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/lib/hive-common-1.2.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException):
>   Cannot create directory
>   /tmp/hive/hdumer/d2562e13-52c9-440d-9fe1-54b66b90ed1d. Name node is in
>   safe mode. The reported blocks 143 needs additional 7 blocks to reach
>   the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 150. The number of live datanodes
>   1 has reached the minimum number 0. Safe mode will be turned off
>   automatically once the thresholds have been reached.  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkNameNodeSafeMode(FSNamesystem.java:1327)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3893)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:983)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
>
> at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Caused by:

> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException):
>   Cannot create directory
>   /tmp/hive/hdumer/d2562e13-52c9-440d-9fe1-54b66b90ed1d. Name node is in
>   safe mode. The reported blocks 143 needs additional 7 blocks to reach
>   the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 150. The number of live datanodes
>   1 has reached the minimum number 0. Safe mode will be turned off
>   automatically once the thresholds have been reached.  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkNameNodeSafeMode(FSNamesystem.java:1327)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3893)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:983)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.mkdirs(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:558)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.mkdirs(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3000)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2970)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1047)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:1036)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createPath(SessionState.java:639)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:574)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
>     ... 8 more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting safemode exception.
So to get out from safemode
Use:

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Answer (score 0):

use this command

hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave

we will get message like "Safe mode is OFF"

then start hive

Answer (score 0):

I had to run as hdfs user:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

(Clouderia CDH 5.10)